# I am getting error on Yii CGridView

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

I have following code for display a grid view, but i am getting huge php notice as follows :

```
$pageSize=Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);

 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'image-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'image_id',
    array(
        'name'=>'file_path',
        'filter'=>'',
        'value'=>'CHtml::image($data->getImgThumb($data->file_path,99,66, false, $data->image_id))',
        'type'=>'raw',
    ),
    'DateCreated',
    'uploaded_on',
    'updated_on',
    array(
        'name'=>'user_id',
        'filter' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'full_name')), 'id', 'dropDownUser'),
        'value'=>'($data->user_id)? $data->user->full_name." (".$data->user->user_name.")" : ""',
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'Title',
        'value'=>  'stripslashes(substr($data["Title"], 0, 200))."..."',
    ),
    'download_count',
),
));
```

And the errors are following : 
/home/drikimages/framework/base/CComponent.php(606) : eval()'d code(1)

Stack Trace :
 /home/drikimages/framework/base/CComponent.php(606): eval()

```
 /home/drikimages/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CDataColumn.php(131): CComponent->evaluateExpression("($data->user_id)? $data->user->full_name." (".$data->user->user_...", array("data" => Image, "row" => 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class model extends CActiveRecord
{
    // .. 

    // .. 


    public function GetUser_display_name()
    {
        if($this->user_id && isset($this->user))
            return $this->user->full_name . " (" . $this->user->user_name . ")";
    }

}


// in zii.widgets.grid.CGridView column array

array(
    'name'=>'user_id',
    'filter' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'full_name')), 'id', 'dropDownUser'),
    'value'=>'$data->user_display_name',
),
```